# SVN: branch issue

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, branch

I just started working with SVN.
I created a dev branch for myself only, so that I can do whatever I want before merging my changes to the trunk.

Unfortunately, when I had to merge, it has been a nightmare.
My tree looked like that:

```
trunk : A-B
           \
dev   :     C-D-E
```

I just wanted to bring back my changes `E` to the trunk.
Everything was compiling and working fine on `E`.
But when I merged, I couldn't compile anymore.
I had conflict that I couldn't understand:

- Some functions add their body changed but the parameter list was still old one.

For ex:

```
void func(int paramA) // from rev B
{
   paramB++; // from rev E and causing compilation error
}
```

- Some new files were added, but some other weren't. SVN was complaining that the files where conflicted because they didn't exist in the trunk. But I can't understand how the some files can be created and other can't.

I have tried plenty of different options with Tortoise SVN (I reverted dozen of time).
I have also read a lot of things about branching with SVN. But I couldn't find a solution to my simple problem. And most of the answers are very old (more than 5 years).

I am used to branches with Git. And everything seem to be logical. But now with SVN I am totally lost!
Could some give me some pieces of advice.
I mean regarding the daily use of the branches not regarding the branch strategy an entire project.
I am just looking for advices to avoid the pain of merge conflicts when they shouldn't occur!

Any help really appreciated!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first issue, the parameters line was apparently modified in B. If you did not modify that line on your branch, SVN cannot see that as a conflict. Git will also not be able to see that, by the way.

Normally this is a good thing. If something changed on trunk but not in your branch, generally you want the merge to combine what happened on trunk with what happened on your branch. But in your case the changes on trunk had a *semantic* conflict (not a line-wise textual conflict) with your branch. You will always need to manually resolve such semantic conflicts; line-based text diff's such as are used by every version control system I've heard of cannot automatically detect or resolve such conflicts.

If you *did* also modify that line on your branch, svn should have marked that file as conflicted. When you resolve that conflict (e.g. by double-clicking the "conflicted" status in TortoiseSVN's "check for modifications" dialog) you get a chance to pick which version of the line is needed, or modify the line by hand.

For your second issue, *new* files introduced on a branch, and not existing on trunk, should always get added without conflict. But, if the files previously existed on trunk and were deleted sometime after you started your branch, you will get a "tree conflict". You will also get a " tree conflict" if someone added a file on trunk with the same name as your new branch file, or if you made changes to a file that someone deleted from trunk.

Dealing with tree conflicts is painful; I'm not 100℅ clear on these but I think you just need to mark it as resolved and `svn copy` the file you want into place with a full file URL.

Comment: It was not obvious in my description but I changed the parameter line in the branch too. That is why I can't understand why the parameter line is not updated during the merge. Regarding the new file, I may have had a file with similar name that I removed in the past. But again since it is useful on the branch I don't understand why SVN complains about it when merging. Finally I almost did what you said: I merged the trunk into my branch and then I copied manually the whole project directory back into the trunk! But I was expecting something cleaner :(

Comment: No, I just meant to copy the specific files that say "tree conflict" when you merge. For the parameter line, you should see svn say the file has a conflict, and allow you to bring up a diff to resolve it. You will need to tell svn which version of the line to use, svn can't know that your version supersedes the one from rev B, since B changed it also.

Comment: I got a diff window but for other conflicts. Not for this one. This is why I got lost during the merge process. It was as if SVN solved the diff the bad way. Well, one of my implicit questions, was "did I misunderstood something?". Your answer tells me that my expectations regarding the merge were correct. I probably did something wrong. But SVN didn't help to catch it! Thanks for your help!